# What is the NSRDB / NREL API "address" query parameter format?

Tags: pandas

What is the proper format for "address" URL query parameter for NSRDB API?  `.../?address=12345+N+Street,+City,+State+Zip` is not working and I cannot find an example that uses "address" instead of latitude and longitude.  I also tried `%20` to represent space instead of `+`.  And I used no spaces, only commas; and no commas, only spaces - nothing seems to work except lat/long parameters.

https://developer.nrel.gov/docs/solar/nsrdb/nsrdb_data_query/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We help solve specific, programming problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you. 
**DO NOT** post images of code, links to code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Comment: This isn't open ended.  It's a very specific question about an API query parameter format.   There can only be one correct answer, and I noticed other NSRDB API questions on here.  And the link is to NSRDB API website.  How else am I to ask this question?  There's no code because it's a a question about a URL format.

Comment: If it is about NSRDB API, why do you have it tagged pandas?

Comment: Because the requested data is best handled by pandas and the developers use it in their examples page. And most questions pertaining to this API include pandas.  And I figured the tag would help categorize the question rather than having no tags.